# Is there any better MFC 2008 Feature Pack Documentation

Tags: windows, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I'm trying to figure out how to use the CDockablePane.

But the just a few total overloaded demo samples (look like marketing samples not intended for programmers) i can't find any Tutorial kind. And the reference is heavy for a medium skilled MFC hacker like me.

EDIT: This is the only documentation i have at the moment: 
[MSDN VS2010 MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk77x1wx.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps ask a specific question about CDockablePane instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Microsoft bought the feature pack classes from BCGSoft, there is more information on their homepage http://www.bcgsoft.com/ in the support area.

Comment: Accepted because this seems to be the only answer. 
I hope someone is writting a new MFC book some day. So much topics are bad documented these days, MFC 9.0, GDI++, Direct2D, DirectWrite etc.

Comment: There has been a new book in writing last year, but unfortunately the project got cancelled.